# Square root of a value using methods on C# window form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been given an assignment on **C# window form** where I get to calculate an input textbox from a user, the user wants to input a value and then presses a radiobutton(square root) then clicks a normal button to get the result. Is it possible to get the result in a textbox (instead of a label)? If so, how do I do that using 'methods' (linking methods to the button_click one)? Also, why do I need to return a parameter value of a method? it doesn't let me execute without returning ;/

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private int square(int A)
        {
            if (rbSquare.Checked)
            {
                Math.Sqrt(A);
                return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(A));
            }
            else
            {
                return A;
            }

        }
        private void btncalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int firstNum = Convert.ToInt32(tbinput.Text);
            int squareRoot = square(firstNum);
            tbResult.Text = "" + squareRoot;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `(int)Math.Sqrt(A);` rather than `Convert.ToInt32`; it is more idiomatic in C# to use a cast here.

Comment: Why are you calling the square root function *twice*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the result in a textbox (instead of a label)?

Sure. Set the text property of the text box, just like you would set the label text of a label.

> why do I need to return a value from a method?

You said that `square` returns an int **always**, but you only return an int if the checkbox is checked. The compiler is reminding you that you need to return an int **always** in order to fulfill the contract that you promised. What value should you return if the checkbox is not checked?

Comment: Yes, logically square roots usually give you a whole number that you multiply by itself gives you that number to square root it. If I don't check the radiobutton not the checkbox, then I get no result

Comment: or if i don't check the radiobutton, it will give me the value input itself without square rooting it

Comment: ok I got the answer but I still didn't understand why return only accepts double numeric values and not integers

Comment: @Oso: I don't understand your question. Your method is typed as returning `int`, so you must return an `int`, not a `double`.

Comment: @Oso: Square roots do not give you a whole number; they give you a fraction. If you ask for the square root of 2, you get 1.414... not 1 or 2!

Comment: the problem in this assignment, it wants me to keep it as an integer, so I can enable square rooting a number that multiplies by itself. Although, the numbers like square root of 2, 3 or 6 do not have 2 numbers that multiply by themselves...